# How to Start Three20 Photo Viewer in Thumbnail view?

Tags: iphone, ios, three20, thumbnails

I followed [How To Use the Three20 Photo Viewer by Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1430/how-to-use-the-three20-photo-viewer) tutorial it was very clear and working perfectly, my question as the title, How to Start Three20 Photo Viewer in Thumbnail view?

I am greatly appreciative of any guidance or help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `TTThumbsViewController` instead of `TTPhotoViewController`. There's a good example of it in three20 TTCategory sample app.

`TTThumbsViewController` also uses a photo source, so you won't have to change that much code. Your Photo viewer should extend `TTThumbsViewController` and implement the `TTThumbsViewControllerDelegate` delegate functions.

You can load the photo source in your viewDidLoad function:

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  NSMutableArray* photos = [NSMutableArray array];
  for (int i=kImagesCount;i>=1;i--) {
    Photo* photo = [[[Photo alloc] initWithURL:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"bundle://%d.png", i]
                                      smallURL:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"bundle://%dt.png", i]
                                          size:CGSizeMake(400, 400)] autorelease];
    [photos addObject:photo];
  }

  self.photoSource = [[PhotoSource alloc]
                      initWithType:PhotoSourceNormal
                      title:@"Select Picture"
                      photos:photos 
                      photos2:nil];

}
```

Comment: thank you I will test that first thing in the morning and let you know.